# How does the TI CCS GEL function GEL_Restart() work?

Tags: debugging, scripting, texas-instruments

I am using Ti CCS version 8.3.1.00004 - inside a gel script, I call the function GEL_Restart(). This resets the DSP (F28335) and the debugger goes to start of main(). Then I set a breakpoint & run to this breakpoint using GEL_Run(). It doesn't run to the breakpoint - stays at current location. Tried stepping ie GEL_StepOver() - nothing works.

Is there something that needs to be done after calling GEL_Restart()? It all works fine from the command menu but not the gel script.

Using a Delfino F28335 development board for target debugging.

Part of gel script below:

```
menuitem "PBE Breakpoint Tests"

Hotmenu HLR_PBE_02x()
{
    if (!GEL_IsConnected())
    {
        GEL_Connect();
    }

    GEL_Restart();
    GEL_BreakPtReset();
    GEL_HWBreakPtAdd("PbitDspcState");
    GEL_Run();

    .....
}
```

It should run to the breakpoint but does not - stays at start of main().